# Jquery not working on Sharepoint Script Editor

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, sharepoint-online

I am working on a project and i have to display a sharepoint list in a bootstrap data table. The list is displaying correctly but i added the class for bootstrap data tables and the table is not displaying as a data table(no sorting and search). I always included a jquery script that makes the checkbox on the head of the table work like a collective checkbox and it is also not working. I have tried the same script outside sharepoint and it worked perfectly. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/css/addons/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm approve">Approve</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm query">Query</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Reject</button>
    </div>
    <table id="dtMaterialDesignExample" class="table btn-table table-striped table-bordered requisition" style="width:100%"></table>
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade modal2" id="basicExampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3>Reject Requisition ?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md close">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- JQuery -->

    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://lotusbetaanalytics.sharepoint.com/sites/Globodox/sitepages/mdb/js/addons/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Globodox/sitepages/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Globodox/sitepages/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
            $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
        });
        $(function() {
            GetRequisition();
        });

        function GetRequisition() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PaymentRequisitionv6');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems("");

            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
            );
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            var RequisitionInfo = '<thead>' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<th><input type="checkbox" id="master"></th>' +
                '<th class="th-sm">ID<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>' +
                '<th class="th-sm">PO Number<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>' +
                '<th class="th-sm">Requester Name<i class="fa fa-sort float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>' +
                '<th class="th-sm">Action</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '</thead>';




            RequisitionInfo += '<tbody>';
            while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
                RequisitionInfo += '<tr>' +
                    '<td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check"></td>' +
                    '<td>' + oListItem.get_id() + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + oListItem.get_item('PONumber') + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + oListItem.get_item('ReqName') + '</td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExampleModal"><i class="fas fa-question"></i></button>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal2"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';

            }
            RequisitionInfo += '<tbody>';
            $('.requisition').html(RequisitionInfo);
        }
        // select with checkbox
        $('#master').on('click', function(e) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
                $(".check").prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(".check").prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to apply Boostrap for all the pages within your SharePoint site

1. Check which master page you are using
2. Open SPD >> Master Pages
3. Edit the currently use master page(s) (You may have two in use: one
   for the publishing side and one for the system side)
4. Located the  tag and within it, add the  reference to
   boostrap (rather it is stored locally or using a CDN)
5. Repeat the steps to reference the following reset css, which will
   avoid conflict between the default CSS provided by SharePoint and
   Boostrap
6. Add the  tag if you are using Boostrap JS

Alternatively, you should consider looking into this one from Microsoft [Office UI Fabric](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles) which does the same, but different libraries. Microsoft builds its own core for style design pattern.

The reason that Bootstrap is not working well with SharePoint Online is that the CDN domain you use for referencing bootstrap file is blocked by Microsoft Cloud platform.